# Is "right-of-way" based on aircraft size?

Tags: general-aviation

I was speaking with an ATP-rated pilot the other day, and he said something that sounded odd: basically the bigger aircraft has right of way once airborne.

Can anyone shed some light on this? As far as I understand, ATC coordinates the landing/departing aircraft; at least at my airfield where there was MD80's, B738 and G/A.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Which way should you turn to avoid another aircraft?](http://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/3575/which-way-should-you-turn-to-avoid-another-aircraft)

Comment: The rules for right of way are rather clearly defined. Basically, you give way to the aircraft on the right; and powered aircraft always give way to unpowered aircraft (i.e. gliders), and all give way to uncontrollable aircraft (like hot air balloons). I've never heard that size of the aircraft matters.

Comment: @ratchetfreak the answer is available in the other question, the question itself isn't a duplicate though.

Comment: I guess as a rule of thumb you could say the less maneuverable an aircraft is, the more aircraft have to give way to it.

Comment: @Maverick283 That is correct.

Comment: If you want to take up a Cessna and pick a fight with a 747, be my guest.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The size of an aircraft plays no role in identifying who has right of way.

The general rule is that for same-class/type (powered or non-powered) aircraft, the aircraft coming from the right has right-of-way and should be yielded to. This is irrespective of the size within the same type, but a question of manoeuvrability. For different types of aircraft, a powered aircraft will have to yield to non-powered aircraft. For more details see the related question below, [ICAO Annex II](http://www.icao.int/Meetings/anconf12/Document%20Archive/an02_cons%5B1%5D.pdf), [FAR 91.113](http://www.ecfr.gov/cgi-bin/text-idx?rgn=div8&node=14:2.0.1.3.10.2.4.7) or another explanation in the [Skybrary](http://www.skybrary.aero/index.php/Right-of-way).

Technically, this means that where separation between IFR and VFR traffic is not provided and aircraft on both flight rules can operate, a Boeing 737 would have to yield to any powered or non-powered aircraft coming from the right.

In most jurisdictions you will find a passage that also details that aircraft should give way to other aircraft that are established on final approach, so a strong situational awareness in the vicinity of airports and airfields is required. Whether separation is provided between IFR and VFR within a traffic pattern, is based on the jurisdiction and the airspace class. In most cases of smaller general aviation aircraft and larger/faster general aviation or commercial aircraft operating at uncontrolled airfields, the smaller aircraft will yield to the faster traffic already on the final approach path out of courtesy or due to *good airmanship*. It is easier and also cheaper for a smaller general aviation aircraft to perform a 360° turn than for e.g. a Learjet on final approach.

See related question: [Which way should you turn to avoid another aircraft?](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/3575/572).

See also this YouTube video: [Airplane Right-of-Way Rules](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uF8YiVOpfpA) - Author: Humble Aviation

Comment: +1 From a legal standpoint, this answer is correct. I would note that in uncontrolled areas, though, it seems relatively common (at least here in the U.S.) for smaller/slower GA aircraft to offer to allow larger/faster aircraft ahead of them, even if the smaller aircraft would normally have had the right-of-way. E.g. A Cessna or Cherokee pilot will often offer to let a Lear land ahead of them if normal sequencing would have otherwise forced the Lear to do a 360 or some such thing to maintain separation. It's a lot cheaper for a Cherokee to fly in a circle than for a Learjet to do so.

Comment: @reirab I will edit my answer to include "Good Airmanship" tomorrow morning.

Comment: That's not airmanship, its courtesy

Comment: @rbp I have worded my answer as such. This will be subjective, but "good airmanship" to me includes a good dose of courtesy.

Comment: "Airmanship can be defined as:[2]
A sound acquaintance with the principles of flight,
The ability to operate an airplane with competence and precision both on the ground and in the air, and
The exercise of sound judgment that results in optimal operational safety and efficiency."

Comment: @rbp That is a purely academic definition of it, it varies from my own definition.

Comment: Courtesy: ": polite behavior that shows respect for other people"

Answer (score 13):

The airborne aircraft right-of-way rules are based on maneuverability, not size. Balloons get first pass, then gliders, airships, powered parachutes & hang gliders, then powered aircraft.

Exceptions include towing or refueling aircraft have right of way over the above, and anyone who declared an emergency has nominal right-of-way over them. Although I don't see the balloon rapidly departing the area just because someone said Mayday.

In practice the bigger aircraft will have right of way. A 747 just doesn't change course all that quickly but a Gulfstream will.

ATC sequences arrivals and departures on a first-come, first serve basis with allowances for wake turbulence - they won't have a Cessna land immediately after a widebody.